# Inject JS global var in Jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a form that is created in Jade ans then compiled. I need to pass the Label name with Javascript.
So the javascript var will look like this :

```
var trans = {"formFirstName": "First Name"}
```

in the form.jade currently its

```
.field.first_name
  label First Name
  .input-wrapper
    input(type="text")
```

But I want First Name to be the variable. I am very new in jade and node. I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the text "First Name" with #{formFirstName} . For more samples, refer to this link http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#text

```
.field.first_name
  label #{formFirstName}
  .input-wrapper
    input(type="text")
```